# bash: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

According to the Windows Linux Subsystem [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/interop), users should be able to execute Windows applications out of the box in WLS bash. However, when I follow the same steps on my machine, I get an error.

```
$ /mnt/c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe
bash: /mnt/c/Windows/System32/notepad.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I'm using Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.14393 Build 14393) with Windows Linux Subsystem enabled, on a 13" mid-2013 MacBook Air.

Bash configuration, e.g. .bashrc, .bash_profile, and a few aliases in .bashrc.d: https://github.com/mcandre/dotfiles

Answer (score 0):

This capability was not added until [build 14951](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/)